# Order of Idolatrous Kings' Courts

Tags: historical-figures, malchut-royalty, melachim-kings-book-of, text, maseches-gitin

The Talmud in [Gittin 88a](http://www.dafyomi.org/index.php?masechta=gitin&daf=88a&go=Go) says that Israel was only destroyed once it had seven courts that worshipped idols: Jeroboam son of Nebat's... ***Pekah*** son of Remalia's, **Menahem** son of Gadi's, and Hosea son of Elah's.

The list follows [chronological order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kings_of_Israel_and_Judah_family_tree), except that in [Kings II 15](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/e/et/et09b15.htm):25, it is evident that Pekah reigned after Menahem, as he killed Menahem's successor Pekahiah, who came to power after his father died at the end of his 10 year reign, and ruled for two years.

**Mhrs"a** edits the Talmud's text, switching the order.

**Does anyone defend the Talmud's text that we have in front of us? What reasons do they give for listing the kings in this way?**

Another switch happens in [Midrash Aggadat Breishit](http://www.brill.com/aggadat-bereshit) in [ch.48](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=26872&st=&pgnum=148&hilite=), when wicked kings of Judah are listed: Jehoram, *Ahaz, Jehoash,* Menashe... Jehoash is Ahaz's great grandfather!

Comment: Have you checked any manuscripts about the proper girsa?

Comment: @DoubleAA good idea, where can I do that?

Comment: Baby Seal, per @DoubleAA's suggestion, I checked the manuscripts in the Hachi Garsinan section of [the Genizah site](https://bavli.genizah.org/), and they all have the same order for the kings.